# Angelleye Adaptive Payments (PayPal) issue - users can't receive money in different currency

Tags: paypal, payment, currency

I'm having a few issues here, I'm using Angelleye:

1.) Currently, when a user clicks to ‘Pay’ on my website, a popup appears and they must then enter their PayPal email address. We take a commission on all items sold on our marketplace, so we need to use Adaptive payments.

2.) In addition, the auction listings that a user creates on our marketplace can be in either $ (USD) or £ (GBP), but it seems that if the user creates a listing that isn’t in their main PayPal currency, they can’t receive payment.

Is the PayPal email popup necessary and can we allow users to receive payments in currencies other than their main PayPal currency?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) There are different options for how to handle the payment flow with adaptive payments.  You can use a pop-up window or a lightbox, for example.  All of the details for how to setup the flow you want are available here:  https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

2) I'm pretty sure this depends on their payment receiving preferences.  When receiving a payment that isn't their primary currency they could end up paying additional fees, so I'm pretty sure they would have to specify that they accept this within their account.  Alternatively, merchants can create separate currency balances within a PayPal account, so you could actually maintain a USD balance and a separate GBP balance within the same account.  This way you could receive money without getting hit with currency conversion or cross-border fees, and the merchant wouldn't have to specifically accept it.

Comment: I can't tell you for certain exactly how they're doing it, but there are different methods you could accomplish the same thing.  With Adaptive Payments you can split the payment in real-time with parallel or chained payments.  This way you would both receive the funds you should at the same time.  Alternatively, you could setup a preapproval profile with the primary receiver, let them receive 100% of the money, but then make a Pay call to pull funds from them to yourself (or whoever the secondary receiver is) accordingly.  You could do the same thing with reference transactions.

Comment: Hi  Andrew, I have issue with using different currencies in chained adaptive payment on one of my web pages.   When use Sender USD - Receiver USD -merchant fee USD, everything works well, but if any of them use some other currencies diff than USD I get "The receiver test.sandbox@hotmail.com does not accept payments in this Currency".  All tested with sandbox emails. I tried to get some help from paypal but they are so unclear with their answers.

Comment: My question for you is: Is there any simple option to handle payment/receivment in different currencies in chained paypal payment ? Or I need to have for any currency diff merchant account (acc with diff currency) ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just a matter of each receiver having their PayPal account setup to accept whatever currency you're sending them.  What exactly did PayPal tell you that is unclear?

Comment: This is last answer  "If a user needs to send multiple currencies they must send multiple files." on my question:I created few test sandbox account and use there testetst@gmail.com email ,  as business.
 
And everything works well when USD currencies is used for all parts , sender-receiver-business who get fee percent of payment (Adaptive payment chained version).
 
But if I change receiver to receive EUR then have problem.
 
 
 
Let summarize:  Adaptive payment paypal allows multiple currencies in chained payment  or not ?